# Do not return row if any value is NULL SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a query that returns 20+ columns, and I do not like this repetition of the `NOT NULL` comparison:

`WHERE c1 IS NOT NULL OR c2 IS NOT NULL OR c3 IS NOT NULL...`

Is there a better way?

I am using redshift, if it makes a difference.

Comment: You said the above `WHERE` clause didn't work, so for now you don't have any solution, and you're trying to find one? Then use as in @garysieling : `WHERE COALESCE(c1, c2, c3, c4, ...) IS NOT NULL;`

Comment: share your sample data where your condition is not working and share expected output from that sample data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best you can do would be "coalesce(c1, c2, c3, c4, ...) is not null" - you'll have to list the columns no matter what. In scenarios where this must be automated (e.g. adding auditing to an existing schema), you would generate queries using information_schema.columns.

Comment: you mean `WHERE COALESCE(c1, c2, c3, c4...) IS NOT NULL`? I've never used `COALESCE()` before, so I'm verifying that it doesn't perform a logical NOT or similar

Comment: Yeah, updated. It finds the first thing that has a value and returns that.